# How to save a Leaflet or OpenLayers map for opening later?

Tags: openlayers-2, web-mapping, leaflet

Can a webmap state be saved to a text file or something for restoring later?
Like if I set up a map with a particular zoom and choose my layers and draw a polygon or two, can it be saved to a file and reopened in the same state later on?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use [PermaLink](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/Permalink-js.html)

Here's an [Example](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/anchor-permalink.html#zoom=0&lat=0&lon=0&layers=B)